# How to test: onClick event - Jest/ Enzyeme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and I just ran a test coverage. This is the only line missing at the moment.

How could I test this line and make sure 100 % is covered

```
   export default class Normalize extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {}
 //    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

 componentDidMount() {
 this.props.normalizeData(null)    
}

 render () {
return (
  <div id='normalize-container'>
    <div id='normalize-header'>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <h3 className='normalized-header'>{this.props.newResponse ? 'Raw Data' : 'Normalized Data'}</h3><br/>
    <div>
      {this.props.newResponse ? null :
        this.props.THead ?
          <div>
            {!this.props.datasourceCatalog ? 
              <div id='next-button-modal'>
                {/*<button title='Proceed To Shape' className='request-button' id='next-btn-ready-modal' onClick={this.props.nextTab}><img src={nextImg}/></button>*/}
                <button title='Proceed To Shape' className='request-button' id='next-btn-ready-modal' onClick={(e) => {this.props.toggleModal(); this.props.nextTab();}}>
                  <FontAwesome
                  className='fa-angle-right'
                  name='view-externallink-img'
                  size='2x'/>                  
                </button>

                <h4>Proceed To Shape</h4>
              </div> : 
            null}

            <div className='normalize-table-container'>
              <div className="data-table-wrapper">
                <table>
                  <thead dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.THead}} />
                  <tbody dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.TBody}} />
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        : null
      }
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using React JS -  jest and enzyme

Testing file :

```
// jest mock functions (mocks this.props.func)
const normalizeData =  jest.fn();
const toggleModal =  jest.fn();
const nextTab =  jest.fn();
const onClick =  jest.fn();

// defining this.props
const baseProps = {
normalizeData,
newResponse:{},
THead:{},
TBody:{},
datasourceCatalog:{},
toggleModal,
nextTab,
onClick,

describe(' Normalize Test', () => {
let wrapper;
let tree;

beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<Normalize  {...baseProps} />));

it(' Should render with all of the props', () => {
```

Render with all props are working - but just need to make sure how to test the line above, on click with 2 props.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
it('should call toggleModal and nextTab functions on button click', () => {
  // Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
  baseProps.toggleModal.mockClear();
  baseProps.nextTab.mockClear();

  // Remove props that would end up hiding the button
  wrapper.setProps({
    newResponse: null,
    datasourceCatalog: null
  });

  // Find the button and call the onClick handler
  wrapper.find('#next-btn-ready-modal').simulate('click');

  // Test to make sure prop functions were called via simulating the button click
  expect(baseProps.toggleModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(baseProps.nextTab).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Note: you can also split these into separate tests, one to test each call separately.

Comment: I get the following error when I run your answer:  Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: What does `console.log(wrapper.debug())` look like?

Comment: `wrapper.find('')` works like `document.querySelector`. `#next-btn-ready-modal` is looking for any element with id `"next-btn-ready-modal"`, so if your id is different then it won't find the element.

Comment: The alternative is to query for _any_ button like `wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')`, but that will error if you have multiple buttons (not to mention it will be a flaky test).

Comment: I undestand, but the id is exactly the same

Comment: log is not giving anything - and i just keep getting the previous error.  Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you. Like what does the test look like, what does the `Normalize` component look like. Checkout this sandbox to see it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9lllw69wr

Comment: i added the component

Comment: let me know if am i missing something

Comment: I updated that codesandbox with the Normalize component. The problem is that with all of these conditionals, the button wasn't being displayed. I'll update my answer with the lines to update the props so the button will be displayed, but I would also advise you to simplify the markup to remove a lot of the conditionals.

Comment: Thanks Matt.. I will look into it later. Did you post on sandbox ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the previous sandbox that I posted with your `Normalize` component and a working test: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9lllw69wr
You can see the tests passing on the Tests tab in the bottom panel.

Comment: Matty , everything worked just fine. Thank you for your time. Question  You used the following to reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
       baseProps.toggleModal.mockClear();
    baseProps.nextTab.mockClear();
    wrapper.setProps({
      newResponse: null,
      datasourceCatalog: null                          //  Wouldn't a wrapper.unmount() do the same thing as well instead of writing all of this again ? Thanks

Comment: @user9191 I'm glad this worked for you :) I'd appreciate it if you mark my answer as the accepted answer. To answer your other questions, `wrapper.unmount()` will not affect the mocks, since it would be executed in the context of Enzyme, whereas the mocks are operating in the context of Jest. And for the way I updated props, you could also rerender the component _without_ those props instead, either way works. `wrapper.unmount` is really only used to test the `componentWillUnMount` lifecycle method to make sure it cleans everything up.

Comment: I see, so i think that might be the reason why some of my other tests were failing. Do you provide tutoring ?

Comment: i tried to apply your method for the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639349/onclick-enzyme-test-error-method-simulate-is-meant-to-be-run-on-1-node-0-f but getting the same error as before.

Comment: matt check this one out : https://codesandbox.io/s/k2qypovm95 I tried to apply your method GO to components - LOA - loa test.

Comment: The first problem is that because you are shallow rendering such a deep component, the buttons aren't being rendered. You could either use `mount` instead of `shallow` or you could try rendering without the Router wrapping the component you are trying to test. Once you solve that problem you will get an error for trying to call `simulate` on 2 nodes instead of one. To fix that I would suggest having some identifying class for each button. Or an id.

Comment: I see. I just got simulate on 2 nodes instead of one  for another example that Im working on it.

Comment: could you give an example when you have a chance

Comment: I updated this codesandbox with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9lllw69wr Look at the Hello.test.js file. It is test 2 identical buttons. You use enzymes `at(index)` function to get a single one. Example: `wrapper.find('button.generic-class').at(0).simulate('click')` calls simulate on the _first_ button found.

Comment: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.